# I can't understand what the read system call does

Tags: c, linux

I don't know what read does after reading 10 characters.

The source code is like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[10];

    read(0, buf, 10);
}
```

I input 10 characters and the program works as I expected, but when I add more characters, the shell runs the extra characters as a command!

[image]

Comment: Your program consumes 10 characters from standard input.  Then it exits. Any unconsumed characters remain in the input stream to your shell.  You'd see the same thing if you had no `read` in your program, except that all characters would remain in the input stream to your shell since your program wouldn't consume any of them.

Comment: You can start with [man 2 read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) which gives a concise (but terse) explanation.

Comment: For example, try `echo "1234567890123" | { ./a.out && read -r line; echo "line: $line"; }` which will show you what remains in `stdin` after `./a.out` is run on the input provided.

Comment: You can experience the same thing without your C program by using this command: `dd if=/dev/stdin bs=1 count=10`. It behaves the same way at the command line. It helps to keep in mind that when you type at the terminal, the program you are interacting with normally does not see any of the characters you typed until you press return. This is known as the so-called "cooked" mode (the default terminal mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't understand what the code does is that the source code is awful - it uses the "magic number" zero as the file descriptor when it could/should be using `STDIN_FILENO` to make it easier to see what it reads data from.

What it might do (if the read doesn't return an error) is read 10 `char` from standard input (maybe waiting for you to press keys if it is connected to terminal input); where it's possible (assuming UTF-8 where codepoints take a variable number of bytes) that 10 `char` might only be (e.g) 3 and a half characters/codepoints.

Of course, the program exits after the read, and when that happens (if standard input was coming from terminal input) terminal input will be connected back to the terminal after the program exits, so any data after the 10th `char` (which can start with a malformed "last part of a multi-byte codepoint") will go to the terminal.

Comment: You say "… (if standard input was coming from terminal input) terminal input will be connected back to the terminal after the program exits…" — I think you could work on the phrasing there.  It's more like "the shell will attempt to read from standard input, and will ger what's left in the kernel's input buffer and will treat it as if you'd typed it at its prompt", but there's probably a better way of saying it.